# Next.js doesn't load jsx

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have been searching about Next.js, the javascript framework of the moment, and I want to begin to practice. The problem is: it doesn't run in my computer by any means.

The natural form on creating a next project is with the command line:

```
npx create-next-app
```

or

```
yarn create next-app
```

The result is a template project with a file structure and a few scripts to run the server. The most basic script runs the server in development mode:

```
npm run dev
```

or

```
yarn dev
```

The result in terminal is the warning:

```
$ yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.5
$ next dev
(node:5348) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution
 of the package at C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
ready - started server on http://localhost:3000
error - C:/Users/maths/Documents/codigos/node/my-app/pages/_app.js 4:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. S
ee https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
>   return <Component {...pageProps} />
| }
|
```

And when I enter the website in localhost:3000, the page on browser shows:

> Internal Server Error

After making the http requisition from the browser, the terminal shows the following message:

```
event - build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
wait  - compiling...
error - C:/Users/maths/Documents/codigos/node/my-app/pages/_app.js 4:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. S
ee https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
>   return <Component {...pageProps} />
| }
|
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\maths\Meus Documentos\codigos\node\my-app\.next\server\pages-manifest.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\require.js
- C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\load-components.js
- C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\api-utils.js
- C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js
- C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
- C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js
- C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at getPagePath (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\require.js:1:
657)
    at requirePage (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\require.js:1:
1062)
    at loadComponents (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\load-compo
nents.js:1:807)
    at DevServer.findPageComponents (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\ser
ver\next-server.js:74:296)
    at DevServer.renderErrorToHTML (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\serv
er\next-server.js:126:120)
    at DevServer.renderErrorToHTML (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-dev-
server.js:34:974)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async DevServer.render (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\ne
xt-server.js:72:236)
    at async Object.fn (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-serv
er.js:56:618)
    at async Router.execute (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\rout
er.js:23:67)
    at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-
server.js:66:1042)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\maths\Documents\codigos\node\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\se
rver\next-server.js:34:1081) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\maths\\Documents\\codigos\\node\\my-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\next-server\\server\\require.js',
    'C:\\Users\\maths\\Documents\\codigos\\node\\my-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\next-server\\server\\load-components.
js',
    'C:\\Users\\maths\\Documents\\codigos\\node\\my-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\next-server\\server\\api-utils.js',
    'C:\\Users\\maths\\Documents\\codigos\\node\\my-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\next-server\\server\\next-server.js',
    'C:\\Users\\maths\\Documents\\codigos\\node\\my-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\next.js',
    'C:\\Users\\maths\\Documents\\codigos\\node\\my-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\lib\\start-server.js',
    'C:\\Users\\maths\\Documents\\codigos\\node\\my-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\cli\\next-dev.js',
    'C:\\Users\\maths\\Documents\\codigos\\node\\my-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\bin\\next'
  ]
}
```

I have tried several things to fix it, create the next project without the script from npx and yarn (by manually installing the dependencies), update versions of node and npm, etc. It seems that the program can't load the jsx, the first error points to the moment when the first jsx component appear in the code. The message says that webpack isn't configured with a valid loader to this code.

Environment:

- Win 10
- npm v7.3.0
- node v15.5.0
- next v10.0.4
- react v17.0.1
- react-dom v17.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your version of Nodejs to 14 or 12 Node version 15 will break your environment. If you want to still want to use 15 get node version switcher and switch the version based on the projects your working on.

Comment: I've installed nvm and so installed the versions 12.0.0, 14.0.0 and 10.13.0 (the minimum version required in vercel's site). Tried in all three versions and the error continues the same :(

Comment: I would try to run npm install then run an npm run build, next.js needs a current build.

Comment: npm install in order to do the correct instalation of all packages configured by create-next-app? I tried that, but still doesn't work.

Comment: I studied a bit of webpack in these days and I think I know in parts where the prolem occours, although I don't know how to fix that in the proper manner. The message points that webpack can't load jsx, perhaps because of a bad configuration of webpack or an obscure problem. The program loads with the transpiled code (that is, react create element insted of jsx), but cannot transpile it